# Is it possible to generate a 1000 digit semiprime without knowing its two primes?

Tags: semiprimes

I studied [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126251/could-g-h-hardy-make-a-product-of-two-primes-so-big-he-couldnt-find-out-which). I'd like to modify it to make it more interesting and more challenging.

Is it possible to generate a (very large, say, with 1000 digits) semiprime without knowing its two primes? If not, is it possible to do so with a high probability? I mean, trying a few times, say, 20,  are you able to get 1 number that is *very likely* to be a semiprime?

[Don Reble paper](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=Semiprime) does not elaborate on how he gets his big semiprime. He simply claims nobody knows its 2 primes. But, he may secretly use 2 known primes to construct his semiprime. Or, he may have a way to generate random semiprimes!

That is the reason why I want to know if it is mathematically possible to generate semiprimes randomly. If it is, how?

Comment: Why care to not know the factors except for crypto ?

Comment: It is out of mathematical curiosity. If you read the Don Reble paper, are you able to trust his claims? If nobody knows the 2 factors, how could he possibly get that semiprime in the first place?

Comment: Generate numbers of form $6ij+i+j$ where $i,j$ can't be written in this form ... Multiply by 6 and add 1 .

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: It's based on extending sieve of Sundaram ...